# how should i add a specific rectangular to an existing image with reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, canvas, frontend

My code base can display the image i fetched from the online server, also i can successfully fetch the bounding box data (it is an array which consists of the a pair of coordinates, width, height), which approach i can use to present this bounding box over the image? canvas or any other way?
If using canvas, or any other approach, where should i add the rectangular component? which file should i embed it? or should I just create a new file and import it?
Also my code base is like when I click on a button, it could console.log the bounding box data, then how could I pass the bounding box data to the rectangular?
In my code base, the react code structure is using functional components instead of using class components..
Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you could have a `<div>` overlaying the image ?